# Google-drive example: oauth2callback not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I need a little help with the C# example program of Google-Drive...

I used this **so-called** "tutorial"/"example":
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

And the code from here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/checkout

I uploaded my (only slightly modified) sourcecode here in case anybody doesn't have Mercurial (I didn't have Mercurial and no admin rights to install it either, and Mercurial is the only way to get the sourcecode...):
http://verzend.be/elt0k13enraw/DrEdit.rar.html

I always get

> "Ressource cannot be found"
>
> Requested URL: /oauth2callback

I don't find this astonishing, as no oauth2callback controller or handler is implemented...

I tried adding a Controller called oauth2callbackController and redirecting to another action in oauth2callbackController.Index, doing

```
return new RedirectResult("/about/about");
```

But that only creates a NULL-reference exception.

So i figured, maybe the wrong controller and redirected to

```
return new RedirectResult("/drive/Index");
```

But that only creates an infinite loop of redirect -> allow -> redirect - allow -> etc.

BTW, the config to change the API key + REDIRECT_URI is in

```
Models\ClientCredentials.cs
```

**Note:** 
The problem aren't my modifications.
The sample also didn't work unmodified, with the exact same error.
All I did was removing EntityFramwork references, and throwing "Not implemented exception" when a method using entity was called.

**Edit:**
Additional information:
What I really wanted to do in the first place is to write a console service that exports my database, LZMA-compresses the exported content, encrypts that with OpenPGP, and uploads the database of my server to Google drive every day at 24:00 o'clock, without any user input.

I got export working without a problem, i got the LZMA compression working without a problem, I got the encryption with PGP working without a problem.
After the end of the working day (grrrr), when I was at home, I was even able to download the example-code with the mercurial installed on my Linux-machine at home, and bring it on the windows machine using SMB...

But now I can't get the sample for the Google-drive SDK working...
And moreover, what I really need is an example for a console service/daemon, not a web-application.
When I created the API key, I saw one could create a key for a service, but there is no example on how to write a Google-Drive service (console application), and no **useful** documentation as well (yea there is a reference, but it's only a reference, IntelliSense provides about the same)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When configuring your app in the API Access tab of the APIs Console, you had to set the root (/) of your web server as the redirect URI and not /oauth2callback.

Assuming that your app is published at www.example.com, just go back to the APIs Console and set it to www.example.com instead of www.example.com/oauth2callback

Comment: Great, the oauth2callback gets appended automagically... I thought that was intended that way. First you enter the data when you register, then you have to change it again to have it the way you entered it in the first place... OK works now. By the way: if i set REDIRECT_URI = "localhost:61422"; and register localhost:61422 in the API, then it says the redirect URLs don't match. If I enter "localhost:61422/"; in the API, then it works... But those two don't match from the programmer's side... Anyway, I can understand that one, it lacks TrimEnd('/') in the comparison. Thanks for answering !

Comment: @Quadayr Just been thru this all myself, pretty much exactly as u although SO has expedited my journey. The trailing forward slash on the URL is important otherwise it gripes about a non match.